# EmptyByteBuf appears in Decoder chain in Netty server

Tags: java, netty

Netty version: 5.0.0.Alpha2

Here's how I add handlers/decoders to my pipeline. (childHandler)

```
childHandler(ch ->
    ch.pipeline().addLast(
      new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE),
      new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(2048, 4, 2, -2, 0),
      new MyDecoder2(),
      new Encoder(),
      handler
    )
)
```

The next thing I do that I send some garbage to the input of this server. LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder throws TooLongFrameException, which is expected in this case.

But what happens futher is `MyDecoder2.decode()` is invoked with `EmptyByteBuf` as input buffer AFTER LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder has thrown an exception.
Where does this `EmptyByteBuf` come from if the previous Decoder should return nothing?

I expect `MyDecoder2` either to receive ByteBuf with correct framing, processed by `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` either receive nothing.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
        at io.netty.buffer.EmptyByteBuf.checkIndex(EmptyByteBuf.java:866) ~[na:0.0]
        at io.netty.buffer.EmptyByteBuf.getBytes(EmptyByteBuf.java:317) ~[na:0.0]
        at spire.broker.proto.MyDecoder2.decode(MyDecoder2.java:27) ~[na:0.0]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeLast(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:371) ~[na:0.0]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:275) ~[na:0.0]
```

Maybe I do not understand correctly how Netty works with chain of decoders in pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code of the `channelInactive()` method of `ByteToMessageDecoder` which a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` extends:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    RecyclableArrayList out = RecyclableArrayList.newInstance();
    try {
        if (cumulation != null) {
            callDecode(ctx, cumulation, out);
            decodeLast(ctx, cumulation, out);
        } else {
            decodeLast(ctx, Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER, out);
        }
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DecoderException(e);
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

Once the channel goes inactive it will call the decode method one last time with an `Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER`. This gives you the chance to clean up if you have made a custom decoder. If you are not interested in that, then you need to override the `decodeLast()` method to do nothing.

Comment: The reason `ByteToMessageDecoder` calls `decodeLast()` with an empty buffer is to make sure to give a user decoder a chance to clean up itself.  If a user is not interested in it, then he or she has to override the `decodeLast()` method to do nothing. Could you update the answer?